# symfony 3 [Semantical Error] The annotation @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Model in class AppBundle\Entity\User does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

when i am trying to log in:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Model" in class AppBundle\Entity\User does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

My entity:

```
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Model()
     * @ORM\Table()
     */
    class User implements UserInterface
    {
    }
```

I have tried to refarcor my code to bundles and everything was working. Now this error shows up

enable_annotations is true

I really do not understand what should be wrong
Does anyone know?

Comment: Why are you writing *@ORM\Model()* ?
It needs to be something like this instead for entity

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity()
     * @ORM\Table(name="user")
     */

Comment: Oh i dont know, but everything was working since now. Anyways thank you for your helpful answer :-)

Comment: AFAICT in Doctrine v2 there was no annotation called `Model`.

Comment: I really do not know where did i get that

Answer (score 0):

My entity has the next syntax:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/** @Entity */
class User implements UserInterface
{}
```

Where is your entity? if you entity is in the folder `Entity` you must change your namespace removing `User`.

Other of my Entities looks like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Usuario
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="table.usuario", uniqueConstraints= {@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="matricula_UNIQUE", columns={"matricula"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Usuario
 {}
```